# change URL of route in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my application I am creating a record in one view & displaying it in other view.
bellow are controller actions

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Domain.Entities.Survey survey)
    {
        ISurveyRepository surveyRepository = new DbSurveyRepository();
        surveyRepository.CreateSurvey(survey);
        TempData.Add("surveyID",survey.ID);
        return RedirectToAction("SingleSurvey");
    }

    public ActionResult SingleSurvey()
    {
        if (TempData["surveyID"] != null)
        {
            ISurveyRepository surveyRepository = new DbSurveyRepository();
            Domain.Entities.Survey survey = surveyRepository.GetBySurveyID((int) TempData["surveyID"]);
            return View(survey);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

There are two views 
1. Create 
2. SingleSurvey

Now when I return view "SingleSurvey" from action "SingleSurvey" the URL displayed on browser is `http://localhost:49611/SingleSurvey`.

But I want to change this URL. What I want is `http://localhost:49611/SingleSurvey/{my record id}/{my record title}`

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route config file add the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SingleSurvey",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
    new { controller = "Survey", action = "SingleSurvey", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then update the create action to pass the ID and title as part of the route values:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Domain.Entities.Survey survey)
{
    ISurveyRepository surveyRepository = new DbSurveyRepository();
    surveyRepository.CreateSurvey(survey);
    TempData.Add("surveyID",survey.ID);
    return RedirectToAction("SingleSurvey", new { id = survey.Id, title = survey.Title );
}
```

In additon, rather than using the TempData to pass the ID it is better to simply read the ID from the URL. To do this, update the `SingleSurvey` action to take in the ID as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult SingleSurvey(int? id)
{
    if (id != null)
    {
        ISurveyRepository surveyRepository = new DbSurveyRepository();
        Domain.Entities.Survey survey = surveyRepository.GetBySurveyID(id.Value);
        return View(survey);
    }
    return View();
}
```

The MVC framework automatically binds the `id` parameter defined in the route to the `id` parameter on the action method. If you need to use the title in the SingleSurvey action you can also add it as an extra parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Add 2 nullable parameters to the get method

```
public ActionResult SingleSurvey(int? id, string title)
{
  // if id is not null, get the survey based on id
  return View(survey);
}
```

then in the post method, redirect with the parameters

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Domain.Entities.Survey survey)
{
    ISurveyRepository surveyRepository = new DbSurveyRepository();
    surveyRepository.CreateSurvey(survey);
    return RedirectToAction("SingleSurvey", new { id= survey.ID, title = survey.Title });
}
```

You might also want want to define a route so that the url is `.../SingleSurvey/someID/someTitle` rather than `.../SingleSurvey?id=someID&title=someTitle`

Side note: Its better performance to initialize a new instance of `Survey` and use `return View(survey);` rather than `return View()` in the case where you are creating a new survey

Comment: I had tried this but dont know what wrong thing I did that time but Now it worked. But still I got "SingleSurvey/someID&title=someTitle"  but not "SingleSurvey/someID/someTitle"

Comment: That's because you have not defined the route correctly or in the wrong order. Can you edit your question with your route definitions and I will update my answer.

Comment: Actually there was no need to pass "int? id, string title" in SingleSurvey. I have added route & it is working very much fine now, thank you.

Comment: You do need to at least pass the `id` (so you can find the survey by id). Do not use temp data for this (refresh the browser to understand why)

Comment: Oh yes, I wanted to eliminate use of TempData & by adding id its done.